# scrollable column with restrained height without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I tried building a sidebar with some listview-like images. The column has a dynamic height and a header which should be always visible but not fixed. The content should be scrollable but without seeing a scrollbar. At first I tried to just push the scrollbar out of the container usind padding-right, but then I wont be able to use the 100% width on the images. So next there was display:table ... I read that overflow only works on display:block, but isnt there some way to make tables scrollable?

I am working with CONTAO as a CMS so I am bound by the templates (which I can edit to some degree). Here's the structure + CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/jf90ktb0/2/

HTML:

```
<aside id="left" class="column">
  <div class="inside">
    <h1 class="columnHeader">Title</h1>
    <div class="mod_article">
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="ce_image">
        <figure class="image_container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://n22.imgup.net/Image_Plac000b.png"></img>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>                  
  </div>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font: 87.5% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    height: 50vh;
    margin: 0px 3% 0px 3%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    right: 0;
}

#left .inside {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}

#left .columnHeader {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #ffd800;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vw;
    width: 20vw;
    display: table-caption;
}

#left .mod_article {
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: table-row;
}

#left .ce_image {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

#left .ce_image img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:
remove `display: table-row;`

and add this line to your css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this one, but with display:none instead of width:0px. This only works for browsers that support webkit. Firefox for example does not support it. It has overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; instead, but when I apply this to the .mod_article DIV it won't allow me to scroll anymore. In addition, it is not recommended from mozilla. FunFact: With overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; applied I cant scroll with the mouse wheel .. but I can "drag" the content (I added some jquery so the content can be dragged by mouse or finger).